# Why is a fundamental mis-understanding of code requirements deemed a typo and off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

This question [Object Required error when I clearly have an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807605/object-required-error-when-i-clearly-have-an-object) was put on hold as off-topic even after it had generated two helpful answers (mine being one of them).

Please vote to re-open [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807605/object-required-error-when-i-clearly-have-an-object) This question is a fundemental mis-understanding of the rules of Excel VBA as the OP thought they could use VB.net style `Workbook.SocialTransform!` to reference the worksheet object. In Excel VBA the correct code is `Worksheets("SocialTransform")` So how is this a typo? It is NOT a typo, it is a programming question that properly belongs on Stack Overflow. Please vote to re-open this question.

Maybe it's becoming popular to shoot at first-time posters, but I find that offensive. We were all beginners once.

Comment: Hint: Starting your request with "I think it's offensive that" makes your question sound very rantish right off the bat...

Comment: @nirk Too good! A typo on a typo question, nice.

Comment: The question just seems to show no research effort, i.e. worthy of a downvote, not a close vote.

Comment: @Dukeling talk about "no effort",... "I have tried declaring it inside the procedure, using set, let, and passing the argument as a range variable."

Comment: @timpeterson No **research** effort. I'm convinced a bit of Googling would've gotten OP to the answer, or OP could've narrowed down the problem quite a bit, and Googled for the correct syntax. Although trying different things can also classify as research. All that said, I'm somewhat indifferent about voting on that question.

Comment: @Dukeling "Have searched" could have easily been "Have googled". Also, "I have tried..." can easily be defined as **research**. The point is you didn't, as I said in my answer, "take the time" to check. I'm not saying you're wrong, I often do each thing I mentioned in my answer. All I wish is that everyone were more self-aware of when they are doing them. As corny as it sounds, "treat others as you'd like to be treated".

Comment: @timpeterson My point is not that a downvote would've been appropriate, it's that a downvote would've been **more** appropriate. But back to defending the point I didn't make - Saying you've searched doesn't cut it, prove it. And searching is a bit broad of a term. The "I have tried" part is a bit gibberish to me, probably because I don't know VB. So I don't really know how much OP tried. Well, ok, let's say "shows little research effort". At the very least that's subjective enough so you can't argue. But I still didn't downvote or vote to close...

Comment: If you don't know VB you can't say what kind of research effort the OP showed. I'm only questioning the points you did make. I didn't say you downvoted it, but arguing it should be downvoted isn't justified if you don't know the context.

Answer (score 5):

There's are 100s of questions on stackoverflow regarding VBA objects. Some of them are closed for various reasons and some of them are open.

Here's the issue from my point-of-view regarding questions like this. They do not tend to generate answers that (as you say) address the fundamental mis-understanding.

Both answers have text around their code. But none of the text describes:

1. why something can look like an object and not be one,
2. how to tell if something is an object,
3. why objects are required in some places,
4. where to look for more information,
5. etc.

That's the problem with most questions about typos, you get answers that don't teach anyone anything except those who have the exact same typo.

Presumably a few of your fellow stackoverflow users thought this questions was off-topic and cast flags to that effect.